# Why are shadows not appearing?

Tags: shadows

Why are my shadows not appearing? I did the lever and slight shadows appeared, but I can't figure out why the piston doesn't have any shadows..... I'm using a spot light with a ton of watts and the bg at a strength of 0.

[image: lever with shadows][image: piston no shadows]

Comment: Hello, I think you are talking about ambient occlusion ? Your object in the second image doesn't seem to "touch" the ground. Maybe you can try to lower it slightly

Comment: If you are in eevee , shadows can be tricky , try to switch to cycles , and then update

Answer (score 0):

It's not shadow but reflective object for your base:

[image]

Despite you use a lot of light source in your scene, non of them actual contribute the "different" for the piston top side.

If you want it to be a little bit more realist, add a bevel modifier to it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I think this is what it was, in the previous image, because i did edit the reflectiveness of the plane. And thanks for he suggestion of the bevel modifier, it really helped.